# Call qweb template inside odoo data template

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I am trying to make an OTP service for login and registration. So I made a module for otp service that is working fine. But here for UI, I made and template that should be called inside the login page to visible the otp box and otp send button. Please see samplae code bellow:

```
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <div name="otp_service" t-name="bulk_sms_otp_service.otp_service">
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
</templates>
```

Now I am trying to call this template inside login view. Please see bellow:

```
<odoo>
  <template id="custom_login" name="Custom login" inherit_id="web.login">
    <xpath expr="//p[hasclass('alert-success')]" position="after">
        <t t-call="bulk_sms_otp_service.otp_service"/>
    </xpath>
  </template>
</odoo>
```

But this call not working. Giving me an error like:

```
External id "bulk_sms_otp_service.otp_service" not found
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code or I am wrong. Please Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read at [Helpers](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/qweb.html#helpers):

> in which case templates stored in the database (as views)

You can deduct that some qweb templates are not stored in database.

You can also read in the [JS QWeb Template Engine](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#qweb-template-engine) documentation that templates defined in files listed in the qweb entry in each module manifest are loaded when the web client starts.

When odoo process `custom_login` template it will try to retrive the `bulk_sms_otp_service.otp_service` template `view_id` (From `ir.model.data`) to [read](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py#L122) the corresponding template and it will fail because `custom_login` templates is not stored in database (In `ir.ui.view`).

Comment: Hey is there any way to do something like a directive? Whenever call directive it will call associated javascript. Like my directive is otp
now if call `<otp></otp>` it will render the otp template.
And there is any way to render a custom view type or widget inside qweb template. Obviously inside website not in odoo form view or other views.

Comment: You can create a [widget](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#widgets), associate the template to it then instantiate it and insert it into DOM or render the template then append the result to an element, you can find an example in [website_forum](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/website_forum/static/src/js/website_forum.share.js#L38)